# Крашится скрипт элементов с id, которые на разных страницах

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, его я прилагаю.
Он делает так, чтобы при нажатии на чекбокс появлялся/скрывался определенный блок с контентом.
В скрипте чекбокс связан с блоком контента через id, который прописан в `const`.

На одной странице находятся:

`link01: 'tab1',
  link02: 'tab2',
  link03: 'tab3',
  link04: 'tab4',
  link05: 'tab5',
  link06: 'tab6',
  link07: 'tab7',
  link08: 'tab8',
  link09: 'tab9',`

На другой странице:

`link010: 'tab10',
  link011: 'tab11',
  link012: 'tab12',
  link013: 'tab13',
  link014: 'tab14',
  link015: 'tab15',
  link016: 'tab16',`

На первой странице все работает, **на второй же скрипт функционирует, если я из него удалю**

`link01: 'tab1',
  link02: 'tab2',
  link03: 'tab3',
  link04: 'tab4',
  link05: 'tab5',
  link06: 'tab6',
  link07: 'tab7',
  link08: 'tab8',
  link09: 'tab9',`

Как исправить, помогите, коллеги. Заранее благодарю!

КОД:

```js
const checkbox2tabMap = {
  link01: 'tab1',
  link02: 'tab2',
  link03: 'tab3',
  link04: 'tab4',
  link05: 'tab5',
  link06: 'tab6',
  link07: 'tab7',
  link08: 'tab8',
  link09: 'tab9',
  link010: 'tab10',
  link011: 'tab11',
  link012: 'tab12',
  link013: 'tab13',
  link014: 'tab14',
  link015: 'tab15',
  link016: 'tab16',
};
function onCheckboxChange(event) {
  const tab = document.getElementById(checkbox2tabMap[event.target.id]);
  if(!tab) { return; }
  tab.style.display = event.target.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
}
Object.keys(checkbox2tabMap).forEach(
  id => document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('change', onCheckboxChange)
);
```

Comment: Добавьте в скрипт проверку на undefined ваших link'ов. Я думаю, что он и на 1ой странице крашится, просто успевает обработать доступные на ней линки.

Comment: @balamutik извините, забыл, уже обновил

Comment: А ошибка то какая?

Comment: Все. Понял, где у вас ошибка. у вас в момент установки листенера на чекбокс нужна проверка на undefined

Comment: @balamutik, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать проверку на undefined?

Comment: Отписал в ответ

Comment: @QuickBrownFox, (чтобы предотвратить дальнейшие проблемы) нужно понимать, что код из ответов на вопросы предназначен вовсе не для копипаста в реальные проекты - он для демонстрации подходов к решению. Тем более что здесь JS выполняется в "песочнице", и не требует вещей типа прослушивания `DOMContentLoaded` (которые *обязательны* на реальных страницах сайтов).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте проверку на undefined, когда вешаете листенер. Вот так:

```
Object.keys(checkbox2tabMap).forEach((id) =>{
    let check = document.getElementById(id);
    if(check) check.addEventListener('change', onCheckboxChange)
});
```